# How to get the division operator in Javascript to work? It thinks it's a Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, division

I'm pulling my hair out trying to find a work around for this.. according to Dreamweaver, and when I run it, javascript thinks the sections between the "/" are a regex definition. How do I fix this to just be division like I want?

```
var totalPrice = 0;
    totalPrice = totalPrice + ((bluRayPrice * filmHours()) + ((filmHours()/3 < 1) ? bluRayPrice * copies1 : ((filmHours()/3)*bluRayPrice) * copies1 ));
```

Comment: What does your code have to do with RegEx?

Comment: Works perfectly here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7UDY/ I think your problem is `according to Dreamweaver`.

Comment: Nothing, that's the whole point of the question.

Comment: @Ayman Safadi, Dreamweaver color coded it with the color assigned to a regex expression, but thanks to Xander I think I just stupidly realized that my formula is just wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dreamweaver is just an IDE**. You should ignore any sort of incorrect highlighting, as the javascript will run as expected and do division when you actually use it.

As a guess though, you should probably put a space between it like

> filmHours() / 3

Comment: Tried a space, Dreamweaver is still color coding it incorrectly, but it looks like it is running correctly in the browser, I just thought it wasn't because I didn't realize my formula was wrong. Thanks for the help Alan

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly fine:

```
var totalPrice = 0, bluRayPrice = 10, copies1 = 10;

function filmHours(){
return 3;
}

totalPrice = totalPrice + ((bluRayPrice * filmHours()) + ((filmHours()/3 < 1) ? bluRayPrice * copies1 : ((filmHours()/3)*bluRayPrice) * copies1 ));

/*totalPrice = 0 + ((10 * 3) + ((3/3 < 1) ? 10 * 10 : ((3/3)*10) * 10 )); */

alert(totalPrice); // 130
```

I also need to point that I have seen many highlighting errors on Dreamweaver. I strongly suggest you to use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), once you use it, you will never want to go back to Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, this should run fine. Just to clean it up a little though:

```
var film_hours = filmHours();
var totalPrice = 0 + ((bluRayPrice * film_hours) + (((film_hours / 3) < 1) ? (bluRayPrice * copies1) : ((film_hours1 / 3) * bluRayPrice) * copies1 ));
```

All I did here was get rid of them totalPride initial set to zero, since it's unnecessary (at least in this context) and shorten the function run to a variable - this way you are dealing with less parentheses and headache.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and did not find any solutions other than as write

```
filmHours()/3
```

like

```
filmHours()*(Math.pow(3,-1))
```

In this way color coding is ok.